# Can't wget my server, but curl works

Tags: manjaro, wget

I can access my server via `curl` and browsers

but I can't access it via `wget`. It is stuck at

```
Loaded CA certificate '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
Resolving ***
Connecting to ***:443...
```

`wget` works with other similar servers though.

I've tried `wget --debug` but it doesn't really show a whole lot more; the last line where it is stuck is still just `Connecting to ...`. The IP that `wget` resolves to is correct.

If I switch my network to the hotspot of my smartphone, I can use wget without problems. Restarting the router didn't help.

It fails on two manjaro installations, wget version 1.21.3. But works on a live xubuntu usb stick, wget version 1.21. I can also use wget from within other servers that are running ubuntu.

The https module of node.js behaves in the same way as wget for me.

Any idea where I can continue to look for problems?

---

Here is the output of wget2:

```
wget2 https://foo.***.com -vd
02.132709.170 Local URI encoding = 'UTF-8'
02.132709.170 Input URI encoding = 'UTF-8'
02.132709.170 Fetched HSTS data from '/home/vs-mango/.local/share/wget/.wget-hsts'
02.132709.170 Fetched HPKP data from '/home/vs-mango/.local/share/wget/.wget-hpkp'
02.132709.170 Fetched OCSP hosts from '/home/vs-mango/.local/share/wget/.wget-ocsp_hosts'
02.132709.170 Fetched OCSP fingerprints from '/home/vs-mango/.local/share/wget/.wget-ocsp'
02.132709.170 set_exit_status(0)
02.132709.170 *url = 
02.132709.170 *3 https://foo.***.com
02.132709.170 local filename = 'index.html'
02.132709.170 host_add_job: job fname index.html
02.132709.170 host_add_job: 0x5626fc4850c0 https://foo.***.com
02.132709.170 host_add_job: qsize 1 host-qsize=1
02.132709.170 queue_size: qsize=1
02.132709.170 queue_size: qsize=1
02.132709.170 queue_size: qsize=1
02.132709.170 [0] action=1 pending=0 host=0x0
02.132709.170 dequeue job https://foo.***.com
02.132709.170 resolving foo.***.com:443...
02.132709.174 has ***ipv6:443
02.132709.174 has ***ipv4:443
02.132709.174 trying ***ipv6:443...
02.132709.174 GnuTLS init
02.132709.189 GnuTLS system certificate store is empty
02.132709.189 Certificates loaded: 153
02.132709.189 GnuTLS init done
02.132709.189 TLS False Start requested
02.132709.189 ALPN offering h2
02.132709.189 ALPN offering http/1.1
```

---

ssl modes:

```
openssl s_client                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ✔  2m 9s  
140269842409280:error:0200206F:system library:connect:Connection refused:crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
140269842409280:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:
140269842409280:error:0200206F:system library:connect:Connection refused:crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
140269842409280:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:
connect:errno=111
```

---

Summary of the one particular case where it breaks:

- I'm in my wifi (hotspot works)
- on manjaro (ubuntu works)
- using wget/node-https/wget2 (curl and browsers work)

Comment: in wireshark if I filter for ip.addr==***, something will pop up with curl, but not with wget

Comment: There's Wget2 - a successor of Wget which uses threads and so is much more faster than Wget. The development usually happens on Wget2. Can you try with Wget2?

Comment: wget2 installation via the AUR fails, can't try. I have updated the post a bit. It works on an ubuntu live usb, it is somehow related to manjaro.

Comment: Guess: certificate or SSL mode issues, which depends on what library wget/curl/the https module use. Debug with `openssl s_client` to see which SSL modes are supported.

Comment: got wget2 to work, see post for log

Comment: added ssl modes to post

Answer (score 3):

**Description**

The problem seems to be that wget and wget2 (and other tools maybe as well) try the resolved IP addresses one after the other. In your case, the first resolved IP 'hangs' at the connection phase (e.g. due to firewall / NAT settings) until it times out. The default for wget and wget2 is to wait forever.

**Work-around**

To "fix" this, make use of `--connect-timeout=N` (N is in seconds, fractions allowed, e.g. `1.5`). You may want to put this option into ~/.wgetrc (a single line `connect-timeout = N`) or into `~/.config/wget2rc` or `XDG_CONFIG_HOME/wget2rc`.

So this is not a general issue with IPv6 vs IPv4, any blocked IP can cause this issue.
In your case, you can also investigate *why* this happens at all and fix it on a different layer.

**Why does curl not hang ?**

Either curl prefers IPv4 over IPv6 *or* curl connects to all IPs simultaneously and uses the first (possibly the fastest) connection for communication.
You can read about the second option [here](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2020/03/16/curl-ootw-happy-eyeballs-timeout/).
If this sounds good to you, feel free to open a feature request [on Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gnuwget/wget2/-/issues).

Comment: thanks, that works! The option is `--connect-timeout` though, not "connection"

Comment: thanks, amended :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using `wget https://foo.bar.com -4` it works

Via the smartphones hotspot ipv6 doesn't seem to work at all and it tries ipv4, therefore the request to the server worked.

It seems our other servers don't have ipv6 configured, which is why those worked.

Via our wifi it tried to use ipv6 and failed.

The various online ipv6 test tools say my computers ipv6 connectivity is working correctly, so I'm assuming our server configuration for ipv6 is broken.

Comment: If ipv6 doesn't work then wget2 should fall back to ipv4. Can you please open an issue at https://gitlab.com/gnuwget/wget2/-/issues?

Comment: See https://gitlab.com/gnuwget/wget2/-/issues/600

Answer (score 0):

The reason why **curl** works and **wget** doesn't can be found in [this comparison](https://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html) made by the creator of curl. It is because it implements [Happy Eyeballs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Eyeballs), one algorithm created for avoiding clients to wait for failing  IPv6 path and protocol.

There were different opinions about this approach. The advantage is that improve the end user experience and the drawback is that hides the network problems, delaying the support of IPv6.

Just to put my example. When I try with a **IPv4-only** site like **s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com** with **curl** the answer is fast:

```
curl -v https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
*   Trying 64:ff9b::34d8:22a0:443...
*   Trying 52.216.29.166:443...
* Connected to s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (52.216.29.166) port 443 (#0)
...
< Content-Length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com left intact

real    0m0,855s
user    0m0,095s
sys 0m0,008s
```

note that **curl** did try with both addresses answered by the **DNS**, the **IPv6** and **IPv4** one. In my case I can not reach those **IPv6** addresses, they correspond to [broken AAAA records](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8305.html#section-7.2).

On the other hand **wget** answer took more time because it tried first all the **IPv6** addresses returned by the **DNS**:

```
$ time wget --debug https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
...
Resolving s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)... 64:ff9b::34d8:2460, 64:ff9b::34d8:ddc8, 64:ff9b::34d8:fba6, ...
Caching s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com => 64:ff9b::34d8:2460 64:ff9b::34d8:ddc8 64:ff9b::34d8:fba6 64:ff9b::36e7:8550 64:ff9b::34d8:d170 64:ff9b::34d9:8578 64:ff9b::34d8:3d40 64:ff9b::36e7:aa98 52.216.209.112 52.216.251.166 54.231.170.152 54.231.133.80 52.216.221.200 52.216.36.96 52.217.133.120 52.216.61.64
Connecting to s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)|64:ff9b::34d8:2460|:443... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)|64:ff9b::34d8:ddc8|:443... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)|64:ff9b::34d8:fba6|:443... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)|64:ff9b::36e7:8550|:443... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)|64:ff9b::34d8:d170|:443... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)|64:ff9b::34d9:8578|:443... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)|64:ff9b::34d8:3d40|:443... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)|64:ff9b::36e7:aa98|:443... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)|52.216.209.112|:443... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x0000560df7694100 (new refcount 1).
... 

real    17m29,487s
user    0m0,022s
sys 0m0,013s
```

Said that, both tools have the `-4`  and `-6` options to force the use of `IPv4` or `IPv6` respectively.